# Probability Events - Total Probability of An Event Happening

Tags: probability

I can't seem to work out the below probability question. Wonder if anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

"10 people have made a booking for a shuttle transfer and the departure time is 10am. If
all customers arrive early, the shuttle will depart earlier. The shuttle will wait until
10:10am if any customers are late. If the probability of customers arriving 10 min earlier
is 0.1, 5 min earlier is 0.2, right at 10am is 0.5, late for 5 min is 0.1, late for 10 min is
0.05, and late for over 10min is 0.05. What is the probability for the shuttle to depart on
or before 10am?"

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you haven't already, take the [tour], and read [help/on-topic] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822),

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be expressed in a binomial distribution if you let `p=0.8` be the probability that an individual arrives on time `(0.1+0.2+0.5)`, and let `n=10` denote the number of trials.

The probability mass function (PMF) of a binomial distribution is defined as

[image]

That is, the probability of observing *k* successes in *n* trials with probability *p*.

Now, the probability whether the shuttle will depart on (or before) time, is equivalent to the probability that all individuals arrive at least on time, that is `P(X = k)` where `k=10` successes.

Using the above PMF we obtain

[image]